# New Photos App on Yosemite Isn't Syncing Smart Albums to my iPhone or iPad

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization, photos, photos.app

All my photos transferred just fine from iPhoto to Photos. My albums (smart and regular) are also all there too. I'm using iCloud to sync my library to my iPhone and my iPad and at first it removed all my photos from both devices and then re-downloaded them. So now all of the photos are on my devices but when I go to albums on my iPhone or iPad there are only the regular Albums and none of the Smart Albums I have on my Macbook Pro. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Smart albums are not supported on iOS.

Comment: That can't be true. My smart albums from iPhoto synced to my iPhone before.

Comment: Photos is a completely different application and some features didn't carry over.  It's an obvious feature for a future release but it's not there now. I "mirror" my OS X smart albums into regular albums if I want them on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

To sync an smart album in Photos with Yosemite -

1. Select *the content of* the smart album
2. Click the plus sign and select "album"
3. The smart album pictures should appear in your new album
4. The syncing should begin immediately

The new album isn't smart though, so you need to repeat this if new photos matching the criteria of the smart album get added to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have a Photos smart album that only contains video it DOES transfer to the iphone via itunes sync. A smart album with pictures does not transfer.